# Como o representar fluxo de um caso de uso que estende\inclui outro caso de uso no documento de especificação?

Tags: uml, casos-de-uso

**Meu caso de uso:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Exemplo de como estou fazendo a especificação do fluxo:**

[...]

1. Fluxo x.
2. Fluxo y.
3. Fluxo z.
4. Aqui precisaria entrar a parte do caso de uso **"Fornecer Identificação"** \ **"Cadastrar Times"**

**Minha dúvida:** Na hora de fazer a especificação dos fluxos do caso de uso **"Realizar Aposta"** \ **"Administrar Times"** qual seria a forma mais recomendada de descrever que esse caso de uso tem um `<<extends>>` ? E no caso de ser um `<<include>>` ?